# Is it possible to read EXIF data with R?

Tags: r, exif

I need to manipulate some image files based on their EXIF data. Can something like this be done in R? I have not seen any R functions which could read EXIF data directly.

Comment: `library(sos); findFn("exif")`

Comment: I haven't tried, but it seems that since the question a way has appeared: https://www.r-bloggers.com/extracting-exif-data-from-photos-using-r/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The **adimpro** package may be useful. It maintains the EXIF data as a `comment()` on the imported image. (not used it myself though.)

Answer (score 2):

I could not find an R package that did it natively either, so I implemented my own at https://github.com/cmartin/EXIFr

As of now, it only reads a subset of tags I was using for a project, but I could easily extend it to suit your needs.

For example, to read the aperture value :

```
read_exif_tags(image_path)[["ApertureValue"]]
```

Answer (score 1):

It is probably faster and more versatile to use exiftool (http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/)

> system("/usr/local/bin/exiftool   pathimagename.img")

Answer (score 0):

I tried adimpro (too complicated for me- needs other packages etc) and EXIFr (got errors). exiftool worked, but I had to figure out a way to get the results of the system call into R. Heres how (you have to add , intern = TRUE):

```
1) install (http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) for your OS
2) use this in R: varName <- system("/usr/local/bin/exiftool path/example.jpg", intern = TRUE)
```